# DC-DC buck converter duty cycle issue

Tags: pwm, dc-dc-converter, buck

I want to make DC-DC buck converter with a PWM controller, gate driver, and MOSFET switch. But I can't find the PWM controller that matches my requirements: input voltage 40 V, output voltage 24 V with variable frequency. There are too many ICs that support 40 V supply voltage but with only 45-50 % duty cycle like [TL494](https://www.ti.com/product/TL494) and [UC3525A](https://www.ti.com/product/UC3525A?keyMatch=&tisearch=search-everything&usecase=partmatches), I think it is impossible to get 24 V output according to the 60 % duty cycle needed for it. Is there an IC that supports these requirements and I can't reach it or there is a way to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you are not mixing up boost converter controllers with buck converters. Boost converters have stability difficulties above 50% duty cycle, buck converters don't. I found a number of devices with a simple search that meet your requirements. Although your requirements need more detail.

Answer (score 1):

"Shopping questions are off-topic", but there does exist a class of devices that are mid-voltage, low-dropout-compatible, frequency-adjustable DC-DC buck converters. Refer to several of the entries in the Diodes Inc AP6xxxx series such as the AP64350:

> **Bootstrap Capacitor and Low-Dropout (LDO) Operation**
>
> To ensure proper operation, a ceramic capacitor must be connected between the BST and SW pins. A 100nF ceramic capacitor is sufficient. If the
> bootstrap capacitor voltage falls below 2.3V, the boot undervoltage protection circuit turns Q2 on for 300ns to refresh the bootstrap capacitor and
> raise its voltage back above 2.55V. The bootstrap capacitor threshold voltage is always maintained to ensure enough driving capability for Q1.
> This operation may arise during long periods of no switching such as in PFM with light load conditions. Another event that requires the refreshing
> of the bootstrap capacitor is when the input voltage drops close to the output voltage. Under this condition, the regulator enters low-dropout mode
> by holding Q1 on for multiple clock cycles. To prevent the bootstrap capacitor from discharging, Q2 is forced to refresh. The effective duty cycle is
> approximately 100% so that it acts as an LDO to maintain the output voltage regulation.

More trivially, do a search on your favourite parts vendor for Vin >= 40, Vout >= 40 and options abound.

Comment: I wish we could convert all stupid shopping question comments (not your fault) into intelligent design specification ones

Answer (score 1):

**A:**  Non-standard analog requirements for signal conversion with unusually high input voltage wasted are unpopular for mass production targets.  But easy to design with a Quad Op Amp and a 24V LDO regulator.  Rail-to-Rail 45V types do exist without crossover distortion and are low-cost but need a way to limit output like the [onsemi NCV33074](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/onsemi/NCV33074DR2G/2683841).

All you need to do is write a better design spec. (including budget)  in order to choose the best design.

**B:**  Considering the maturity of DCDC IC's that include pulse modulators for this voltage range are far less cost ($1.33) than any DIY design and better performance. I suggest you define your goals and learn from one of the best.  For example my spec was [24Vout 2A max 40Vin max](https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/switching-regulator/export/213) High efficiency was preferred and this sync. converter operates in PFM rather than PWM.
You do have to figure out how to make the custom inductor. L/R = 2ms  6A
[image]

There is no need to load this with a huge cap, with low ESR/DCR Rs, RdsOn components but a soft start up spec is needed. This demands more energy , start time and surge current.

However the biggest oversight error are your overall missing system performance specs.

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm25148-q1.pdf